# Unable to import andThen in acceptance test - ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am quite new to ember.js project where i am trying to write my first acceptance test for testing my root path works. I am following the below [tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/tutorial/acceptance-test/) . I was unable to import "**module-for-acceptance**" from the helpers as its deprecated. when i run the below test i am getting an error which says (0 , _testHelpers.andThen) is not a function. I had also gone through [ember js discussion post](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/referenceerror-andthen-is-not-defined/14266)  and imported **andThen**. It does not seem to work . How can i import andThen and make my test work . Thank you.

**Test case**

```html
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { visit, currentURL ,andThen } from '@ember/test-helpers';
import { setupApplicationTest } from 'ember-qunit';


module('Acceptance | list rentals', function(hooks) {
  setupApplicationTest(hooks);

  test('should redirect to rentals route', function (assert) {
    visit('/');
    andThen(function() {
      assert.equal(currentURL(), '/rentals', 'should redirect automatically');
    });
  });

});
```

**Log**

```html
Died on test #1     at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:7357/assets/tests.js:8:21)
    at processModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:3765:16)
    at module$1 (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:3790:4)
    at Module.callback (http://localhost:7357/assets/tests.js:6:21)
    at Module.exports (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:111:32)
    at requireModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:32:18)
    at TestLoader.require (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:13736:9): (0 , _testHelpers.andThen) is not a function@ 60 ms
Source:  
TypeError: (0 , _testHelpers.andThen) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:7357/assets/tests.js:10:32)
    at runTest (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:5618:30)
    at Test.run (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:5604:6)
    at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:5831:12
    at processTaskQueue (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:5197:24)
    at advanceTaskQueue (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:5182:4)
    at Object.advance (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:5168:4)
    at unblockAndAdvanceQueue (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6944:20)
    at begin (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6978:5)
    at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6219:6
Tried to restart test while already started (test's semaphore was 0 already)@ 61 ms
Source:  
    at resume (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6171:5)
    at done (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6362:7)
    at Class.asyncEnd (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:13822:9)
    at asyncEnd (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:68040:15)
    at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:67197:31
    at invoke (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:65509:16)
    at Queue.flush (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:65400:13)
    at DeferredActionQueues.flush (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:65597:21)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember testing has moved to an async/await pattern instead of using `andThen` and other global test helpers.  That tutorial is for a fairly old version of Ember, you'll have a lot more success with a [more recent guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/testing/acceptance/). Even if you are not ready to update to a newer version of ember I would still recommend following the new test patterns as they are significantly easier to read and write.

If you want to test it with `andThen` you wouldn't need to import it as it was provided as a global, but you need to make sure your testing dependencies are correct. I would start with comparing your current `package.json` with the [default for ember apps at that time](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output/blob/v2.10.0/package.json#L17) you may need to downgrade some packages in order to get access to the old imports and global test helpers.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.recent guide helped me a lot.